# Bootstrap dropdown menu is hiding behind the container

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have this navigation in a site.  this contains a two level dropdown menu. which works just fine !

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav pull-left">
<li class="active"><a href="http://example.com">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" tabindex="-1" data-delay="200" data-close-others="true" href="#">Category<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-container=".white body" aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu" style="z-index: 999999999 !important; display: block; position: absolute;">      
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a class="dropdown-toggle submenu-toggle" data-id="1" tabindex="-1" href="http://ec2-54-254-210-87.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/category/mobile-phone/1">Mobile Phone&nbsp; <span class="badge badge-info">518</span>   
</a>   
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a class="dropdown-toggle submenu-toggle" data-id="28" tabindex="-1" href="http://example.com/motorcycle/28">Motorcycle&nbsp;   <span class="badge badge-info">100</span>   
</a>           
<ul class="dropdown-menu submenu-menu" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://example.com/walton">Walton</a></li> 
</ul>               
</li> 
</ul> 
</li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

But when the main dropdown gets longer (increases in height)  most of the menu is hidden inside the main container div that followed by the header of the site which contains the nav bar.

**I tried so far:**

- setting z-index within the  tag inline and made it !important.
- tried to set the z-index of the  to -1 so
  that the dropdown gets more stack top power than the main container.

But nothing worked !

Comment: Is the dropdown is posting relative to header.If yes make it absolute and give z-index let say 1000...

Comment: You either have overflow:hidden specified on the main container, or the z-index of it is lower than that of the content...

Comment: Z-index is relative to parent. If the parent is lower, it's not going to matter what overrides you try to do.

Comment: I have the blue header section has a position static and z-index is auto. and dropdown's default position is absolute and z-index is 1000  which I have made 999999 !important. @Aibrean

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava The dropdown is positioned relative . and header is static itself in position.

Comment: you have given some particular height to header with `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Whola ! Whola! You r absolutely right ! I should have understood that ! it's a great shame for me ! I have to learn debugging techniques again.. Ohhh.. It took my valuable 4 hours !!!! Thanks Arpit.

Comment: No issue ;)....we are here to solve your problem.